# Html table design - can I make one row wider than other?

Tags: html, css

I have site with ancient table design. To stretch out logo and footer is impossible and customer at common not ready to stretch out historical header and footer. But currently customer want to make site body wider that header and footer. So, I have

```
  <table width="500px">
  <tr> ... header ... </tr>
  <tr> ... body   ... </tr>
  <tr> ... footer ... </tr>
  <table>
```

So, I need save width header and footer to convenient 500px, but make body width for 1000 px. Strange wish and contradict to whole logic of table design, but... is it possible?

Comment: Why not take this opportunity to ditch the table for your layout, since that's 90's thinking? Tables are for tabular data, not layout, use CSS instead

Comment: A quick n dirty fix: `table,tbody,tr{display : block ;} table {min-width :100%}tr{max-width :500px;margin :auto ;}tr:nth-child(2){max-width :1000px}` not tester but should be a start before updating your HTML to something more up to now days ;)

Comment: @j08691, answer is very simple, site has million pages and customer is poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll have to widen the whole table, but you can make it **appear** as if the header and footer rows retain their original width. Create a second column for the additional width, then have the header and footer use column 1 only (using a blank cell in column 2), and have your body span both columns.

The snippet illustrates how it could look. Note that instead of 500px and 1000px, I have used 300px and 500px so that the output is small enough to fit in the preview box.

```css
table {
  width: 500px; /* new wider width */
}
td:first-child {
  width: 300px; /* original width */
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> ... header ... </td>
    <td>left blank</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> ... body   ... </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> ... footer ... </td>
    <td>left blank</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```